# Edited GIF slower than original

Tags: animation, gif

I've imported the GIF, edited some layers, and now when I save it for web, it's considerably slower.

[Original GIF](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1204962/screenshots/4651504/hamster-loader.gif) vs [Edited GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdY80.jpg)

Why is this happening, or rather, how can I prevent it?

Comment: What software were you using?

Comment: I used Photoshop CS6

Answer (score 4):

The **delay** in frames.

The original has a `0.04` delay for each frame. Yours has a `0` delay. Setting the delay back to `0.04` corrects the issue.

Original:

> [image]

Yours:

> [image]

Yours with delay reset:

> [image]

Comment: Damn, that makes no sense... How can a 0 delay be slower than a 0.04 one?

Comment: My guess is that it merely **controls** the delay and without a control the browser decides how fast frames move. But you're right, it makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks again, you've saved me a ton of hair.

Comment: Adobe puts a lot of effort to push the usage of somethings that are somehow standardized to make its programs "different". In this case, the GIF file accepts values of 1/100 of a second as a "frame rate". So a "delay" (what a nonsense) of .04 is 1/.04 = 25 so it is 1/25 sec. But when you have 0 you have 1/0=? or no valid, so the value is reset to some other value, probably 1/10th of a second.